# No matching version found for @rushstack/eslint-patch@^1.1.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npx

I'm trying to create a REACT app and I keep getting the following error. I have reinstall node.js to the latest version. I can't find anything regarding this error. What can I try next?

> $ npx create-react-app notes-frontend
>
> Creating a new React app in C:\Users\brad\OneDrive\Documents\Old Drive
> D\LearnReact\MERN\notes-frontend.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for
> @rushstack/eslint-patch@^1.1.0. npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or
> one of your dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package
> version that doesn't exist.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\brad\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-05T00_17_43_589Z-debug-0.log
>
> Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
> error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting notes-frontend/ from
> C:\Users\brad\OneDrive\Documents\Old Drive D\LearnReact\MERN Done.

When I execute NPX I get this.

> $ npx Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.2037] (c) 2019 Microsoft
> Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\brad\OneDrive\Desktop\test>

Comment: Did you follow the CRA getting started guide, which instructs to delete the globally installed version of CRA (if you have one)?

Comment: I got the same error when I tried this: npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f

Comment: I see a space in one of the folder names in your path. Can you try in a path without one?

Comment: Removing the space did not work for me, it has to do with it no longer supporting the global installation of Create React App. I having issues uninstalling it.

Comment: I don't think it was ever recommended to globally install it, it just became a common fallacy in a bunch of tutorials etc. Maybe your question should be revised to focus on uninstalling.

Comment: Yes, I have to delete the global installed Create React App package.